# Invoice design - per item price, tax, and discount

Tags: database-design, data-structures, business-logic

Not being much of a business-person, I'm unsure how I should design the data structure (both in-memory and the database schema) for invoices in my application (which handles accounts receivable from clients).

My question concerns invoice line-items. It's already a given that items have a name or textual description, a price-per-unit, and a quantity value (thus the price-per-unit multiplied by the quantity gives the line total). However I don't know how I should factor-in per-line discounts and taxes, especially when both can be expressed as a percentage or as a fixed amount, and then I need to consider the order of operation (is a fixed-price discount done before or after a percentage tax increase?).

Here's the DB schema I'm thinking:

```
InvoiceItems
    InvoiceId        bigint
    ProductId        bigint NULL       -- Optional reference to the product this item is generated from
    Description      nvarchar(255)
    PricePerUnit     money
    Quantity         decimal(9,4)
    AdjustmentBT     money NULL        -- before-tax fixed-value price adjustment 
    AdjustmentBTPerc decimal(9,4) NULL -- before-tax percentage price adjustment
    Tax              decimal(9,4) NULL -- tax as a percentage
    AdjustmentPT     money NULL        -- after-tax fixed-value price adjustment 
    AdjustmentPTPerc decimal(9,4) NULL -- after-tax percentage price adjustment
```

So the line-total is this function:

```
LineTotal = ( ( ( ( ( PricePerUnit * Quantity ) + AdjustmentBT ) * AdjustmentBTPerc ) * Tax ) + AdjustmentBT ) * AdjustmentPTPerc
```

Or in RPN:

```
LineTotal = PricePerUnit Quantity * AdjustmentBT + AdjustmentBTPerc * Tax * AdjustmentBT + AdjustmentPTPerc *
```

As I'm not someone who works with invoices at all, and with limited feedback from the person I'm writing this program for, I don't know if I'm over-thinking it or not. I need to provide sufficient flexibility but without being complicated - and with this approach it means each invoice item is going to look like this:

```
Description | PricePerUnit | Quantity | Before-tax Adjustment | Tax | Post-tax Adjustment | %computedTotal%
```

...where the Adjustment fields interpret the entered value as a percentage or fixed value depending on the presence or absence of the '%' character.

Comment: Silverston Data Model Resource Book Vol 1. http://www.amazon.com/books/dp/0471380237

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the taxation is constant for all items and as added at the end of the invoice. If each line can have its own discount, then the final price for each line would be

```
finalprice = quantity * unit cost for item * (100 - discount) * 0.01
```

That's if you want to store discounts like 20% or 40%. Adjust your formula accordingly.

Then the invoice total will be sum (finalprice) * (100 + tax) * 0.01, again if you store your tax in the form 15% or 20%.

The tax adjustment - presumably rounding - would be applied after tax.

Let's say that the sum of the finalprices is 120.20 and you have 15% tax. This means that the calculated tax would be 120.20 * 0.15 = 18.03, meaning a final price of 138.23. Presumably you want to round this down to 138.00. As the taxman always wants his full cut, this means that the tax will be (138.00 * 0.15)/1.15 = 18.00. Thus the adjustment will be 0.20. This could be presented as follows

```
total            : 120.20
rounding discount: -00.20
total pretax     : 120.00
tax (15%)        :  18:00
invoice total    : 138:00
```

I hope that this is clear enough. I used to be an accountant before I became a programmer.

{Extra}
If you do have varying amounts of tax, then ignore what I wrote in a comment below. It would be more efficient to group the order lines according to the tax rates in the following manner

```
total for 15% tax: 120.20
tax (15%)        :  18.00
total for 0% tax :  26.50
grand total      : 164.70
rounding discount:   0.30
invoice total    : 165.00
```

In terms of fields within the invoice table, the only figure that needs be stored is the rounding discount. All the other fields can be calculated by iterating over the order lines table. A small amount of denormalisation can be allowed by storing the total tax to be paid, but you're going to have problems if you start storing the totals - in the above example, there are only two tax rates, but what happens if you have three? This would break first normal form (storing repeating groups).

Comment: I'm uncertain about taxation being uniform, that's why I've added per-item taxation, because certain items can be subject to the 20% VAT rate, but others to a 0% or 10% rate. All the same I might be making things too complicated and offering the user a simple single line-price might be better.

Comment: If you have separate taxation per item, then treat it like you treat each line's discount. As I wrote, the tax man wants his full cut, so you'd still have to the total of each line (including tax), then do the rounding. In terms of accounting, the tax will be whatever was calculated, but the rounding discount will reduce the income.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not getting support from your client about "how things work", you're already in trouble. The simple fact is that you don't have the "acceptance" criteria for this portion of your application, and it happens to be rather important.

You really need to get better requirements from them as to how this is calculated.

Many times discounts are additive, not multiplied.

Specifically:

```
$100 with a 10% discount (on sale) and 20% discount (coupon)

Discount total Additive: $100 * (10% + 20%) = $100 * 30% = $30 discount

Discount total Multiplied: 
    $100 * 10% * 20% =
    $100 * (100 - 10%) * (100 - 20%) =
    $100 * .90 * .80 =
    90 * .80 =
    $72 = $28 discount
```

So, clearly, it's important to know what the rules are for these cases.

Taxes, for example, are pretty much always added. If you have a 5% state tax and a 2% local tax, you'll get taxes of $5 + $2.

You are better off putting your discount information in to a separate table, and using a code for it.

A simple table:

```
discount_key - primary key
discount_code - code for humans
description - what kind of discount
percent_discount - percent of discount - OR - 
fixed_discount - Fixed amount discount
gl_acct_id - GL account to post discount amounts to.
```

And then tying each line item (AND the invoice...) to the discount type. The reason is that in many case the KIND of discount matter (a 10% off coupon discount is different from a 10% off opened item discount). For account purposes, these discounts tend to be tracked individually.

Your tax information should likely be tied to the item. If you only have one tax jurisdiction, then a single percent amount could work, otherwise you would point to a similar table like the discount table. If there are multiple jurisdictions, then you would point to a tax group that would be a master to a list of individual tax rates.

You should have a discount that applies to the invoice as whole as well (20% off everything, kind of thing).

In the end, you would have a detail line table that would have the product, qty, discount code, discount total, tax total, line total. This will work well for printing the invoices. For posting, if you have multiple taxes, you'll have to recalculate the individual taxes. You may well be better off with individual tax lines for each line item. Otherwise you can work off of the detail line numbers directly.

Anyway, the real take away here is you need to have a better understanding from your client about the requirements. Discounts are a notorious area of complexity. One place I worked, we redid the discount system, pretty much completely, every year for 4 years. (But don't forget to keep the old code, we have old invoices using the old systems!) This is because MARKETING drives discounting policy, and marketers are fickle.

Oh, and welcome to accounting. "How hard can it be?"

Comment: Thanks, I wouldn't have thought to represent discounts that way. The reason I don't have details from my client is because he's actually on holiday right now and I said I'd have a prototype ready for when he gets back, no-doubt he'll set me straight then.